# eslint in a Nuxt app is suddenly not working - getting Error: No ESLint configuration found

Tags: eslint, nuxt.js

I launched a project last week. All worked perfectly.

I come back this week and now eslint is giving me the Error: No ESLint configuration found error.

I have the eslintrc.js in the root of my project.

Here's the relevant section of my NUXT CONFIG file.

```
extend(config, ctx) {
  // Run ESLint on save
  if (ctx.isDev && ctx.isClient) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      enforce: 'pre',
      test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
      loader: 'eslint-loader',
      exclude: /(node_modules)/
    })
  }
},
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the setup file for eslint exist?(.eslintrc.js)

Answer (score 0):

Please add these lines

```js
extend(config, ctx) {
  if (ctx.dev && ctx.isClient) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      enforce: 'pre',
      test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
      loader: 'eslint-loader',
      exclude: /(node_modules)/,
      options: {
        fix: true
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you link your source or shortly explain the changes? Thanks :)